# How can I view all questions asked on my account?

Tags: support, questions, profile-page

I'd like to view all my questions on all my sites at once. Is there a way to do this?

Currently, when I click on the "Questions" tab in my profile, it only shows me the questions I've asked on that site.

Comment: Your Network Profile option (top left of your profile page) has that information: http://stackexchange.com/users/6527533/pro-q?tab=activity

Comment: This is limited to the latest 100 only @Jon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your [Network Profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/6527533) you can filter by "posts" under the [activity](https://stackexchange.com/users/6527533/pro-q?tab=activity) tab. It's an admixture of all your questions and answers and limited to 100 posts, however.

Questions and answers with a score of at least five will be displayed in separate lists on the [top](https://stackexchange.com/users/6527533/pro-q?tab=top) tab, which is the default.

You can reach your network profile by going to your profile on any site and clicking the "Network Profile" link.

Comment: So in other words, there's no way to do explicitly what I want, but I can at least look at some of my most recent posts which will hopefully contain the questions I want to see.

Comment: If you read the linked duplicates, there are ways to use the data explorer to get at the data you want.